# Why is sometimes geometryType not returned in JSON from ArcGIS Server layer REST API?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, development, rest

Does someone know why the  geometryType not always get returned from ArcGIS Server layers?

According to the API documentation [Layer / Table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/index.html) the geometryType is returned on layers:

```
//properties specific to layers only 
"geometryType" : "<geometryType>",
```

But on some layers the resulting JSON looks like this:

```
"geometryType" : "",
```

The layers I'm testing on is our own and as far as I can see they are set up in the same manner,:capabilities with mapping and web access enabled. Dynamic layers. Some layers return the correct geometry type and some don't.

Update: Clearing the cache [See rest admin](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/admin.html) does not help.

Comment: Did you try clearing the REST API cache?

Comment: @Adam-Armour No, but I did now and it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the SHAPE field visible in your MXD?  If you obscure this field it is difficult to determine the nature of the geometry, so it may not display the geometryType.

We've had troubles with geometry operations with ArcObjects when the user hid the OBJECTID and SHAPE fields in ArcMap.

Comment: Correct, all layers that work has a field with the type esriFieldTypeGeometry and the layers that don't work are missing the field.

Comment: Found the same explanation on the ESRI forum as well: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2399&t=283085